# Python/Tkinter ¿Cómo capturar correctamente los clics del ratón en menú contextual?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo un canvas donde puedo cargar imágenes y textos.
Para moverlos y realizar varias ediciones uso la función `find_withtag(CURRENT)`, ya que al poner el puntero sobre el objeto, le añade el `tag CURRENT` y así se puede editar el objeto sobre el cual está el puntero.
Pero al tener un menú contextual (`pop-up menu`) al dar clic con el botón derecho del ratón, y el cual contiene varias opciones, por ejemplo si al final del menú está la opción "Eliminar elemento", no es posible usar `find_withtag`.
Me explico, hago clic derecho sobre un elemento para que aparezca el menú contextual sobre él con las opciones, pero al mover el puntero hasta la opción deseada a veces el puntero ya deja de estar sobre el objeto en cuestión y pasa a estar sobre otro o en espacio vacío del canvas y al dar clic sobre la opción ya no la ejecuta porque hubo que mover el puntero hasta la opción fuera de la zona sobre el objeto.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar eso?

Ejemplo del código:
Lo de la ventana lo damos por obvio...

```
# Creo el canvas
global canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(main, width=cw, height=ch, bg="white", cursor="arrow",
                   selectbackground="red", selectborderwidth=1, selectforeground="cyan")
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

# Función para abrir una imagen y colocarla en el canvas, le agrego el tag
# "SEL" para otra función sobre la imagen 

def abrir1(main):
    global image1
    try:
        pic = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="../")
        canvas.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = pic)
        canvas.create_image(cw/2,ch/2, anchor=CENTER, image=canvas.image1, tags=SEL)
    except:
        pass

# Creo una de las funciones para el menú contextual, en este caso la de borrar una imagen
def borraim(main):
    try:
        canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT) # Aquí detecta a la imagen y le da el tag "CURRENT"
        canvas.delete(CURRENT)
    except:
        pass

# Creo el menú pop-up o contextual que aparecerá al dar clic derecho
# en cualquier parte del canvas, mostrando varias opciones:

menu = Menu(main, tearoff=0)
menu.focus()
menu.add_command(label="Traer al frente", command=lambda:adelante(main))
menu.add_command(label="Enviar al fondo", command=lambda:atras(main))
menu.add_separator()
menu.add_command(label="Borrar", command=lambda:borraim(main))

def popup(event):
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

# attach popup to frame
main.bind("<Button-3>", popup)
```

Entonces por ejemplo, si quiero eliminar una imagen, hago clic derecho sobre la imagen y se despliega el menú, pero para llegar a la última opción del menú debo mover el puntero hasta la misma y dar clic con el botón izquierdo, entonces como el puntero tal vez ya no está sobre la imagen (por que lo moví hasta la opción), ya no detecta a la imagen con `find_withtag(CURRENT)` y no hace nada al dar clic o detecta el objeto que ese momento esté bajo la posición donde está la opción del menú y ejecuta la opción sobre ese objeto y no sobre la imagen inicial. No sé si hay otro tipo de función para que esto se ejecute correctamente sobre el objeto sobre el que se dio clic derecho inicialmente.

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código en la pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: He editado la respuesta para capturar la excepción que se da en zonas vacías. Cuando hagas algún comentario sobre la respuesta deberías hacerlo en `añade un comentario` y no editando la propia respuesta ;)

Comment: Si, muchas gracias. Quise añadir un comentario pero por alguna razón no me permitía añadir el código de error. Por eso lo hice editando la respuesta. Cosas de novato. Voy a probar el código y vuelvo a comentar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar el item al que apunta `CURRENT` al desplegar el menú en una variable global:

```
def popup(event):
    global current_item
    try:
        current_item = canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT)[0]
    except IndexError:
        current_item = None
    menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

def borraim(main):
    try:
        canvas.delete(current_item)
    except:
        pass
```

Si prefieres que el menú no se despliegue sobre zonas vacías sólo tienes que incluirlo en el `try`:

```
def popup(event):
    global current_item
    try:
        current_item = canvas.find_withtag(CURRENT)[0]
        menu.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    except IndexError:
        current_item = None
```